# install and run PHP in Apache Tomcat 6.0 in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: php, windows, tomcat

I've been struggling with this issue for the past 2 days. I've finally decided to post my question here. I am trying to run a PHP script on my Apache tomcat, but I am not able to do that.

I have tried a number of tutorials:

- [PHP 5 on Tomcat 6 Installation](http://blog.jackneer.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html)
- [Running PHP applications in Tomcat 6](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/tomcat6.php)

But it gives me error of "can't load ia 32-bit .dll on a amd 64-bit platform tomcat"..I tried to solve this but no luck becuase the PECL binary file is not for 64-bit system and for the other tutorial which uses javabridge.jar, I am getting error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no php5srvlt in java.library.path".

Comment: "Nothing seems to be working" is probably a bit too generic (read: vague) to get any useful answer.

Comment: OKhey...My bad...I am trying 2 approach to install PHP..one using PECL module mentioned in the tutorial lin kabove..But it gives me error of "can't load ia 32-bit .dll on a amd 64-bit platform tomcat"..I tried to solve this but no luck becuase the PECL binary file is not for 64-bit system and for the other tutorial which uses javabridge.jar, I am getting error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no php5srvlt in java.library.path"

Comment: I dont understand why ppl downvoted before answering to the problem or they only know how to downvote someone's question